# How to draw the surface of the grid in solid mode?

Tags: java, image, 3d, processing

I have this code and I should modify it to do 2 things:

1. draw the surface in solid mode using the basic lighting (`lights()` and a unique `fill()`) and
2. draw the surface with a two color gradient (**red** for low values of **z** and **yellow** for high values, for instance) For that,I was advised use a `fill()` call before each vertex()

This is my code for the 1st one, the problem is that I do not want the grid to show after I have applied the color.

```java
// Drawing a 3D function
float rotX = 0.0, rotY = 0.0;
int lastX, lastY;
float distX = 0.0, distY = 0.0;
// Function steps
int steps = 50;
// z scale
float scaleZ = 200.0;
// z zoom
float zoomZ = -300.0;
// Graphic size
float gX = 500.0, gY = 500.0;
void setup()
{
    size(500, 500, P3D);
    noFill();
    strokeWeight(0.005);
}

float function(float x, float y)
{
    return x*x*x + y*y*y;
}

void draw() {
    lights();
    background(0);

    // We center the results on window
    translate(gX/2, gY/2, zoomZ);

    // Rotation
    rotateY(rotY + distX);
    rotateX(rotX + distY);
    // Centering around (0, 0);
    translate(-gX/2, -gY/2);

    // Function covers
    // 400 x 400 x scaleZ
    scale(gX, gY, scaleZ);

    // Drawing the function
    fill(167);
    drawFunction();

    // Drawing axes
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    line(0,0,0,2000,0,0);
    stroke(0,255,0);
    line(0,0,0,0,2000,0);
    stroke(0,0,255);
    line(0,0,0,0,0,2000);
}

void drawFunction()
{
    float x, y, z;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    float in_steps = 1.0 / steps;

    float[][] matrix = new float[steps+1][steps+1];

    for (y = 0.0, j = 0; y <= 1.0; y+=in_steps, j++)
        for (x = 0.0, i = 0; x <= 1.0; x+=in_steps, i++)
            matrix[i][j] = function(x, y);
    stroke(167);
    for (j = 0, y = 0.0; j < steps; j++, y+=in_steps) {
        beginShape(QUAD_STRIP);
        for (i = 0, x = 0.0; i <= steps; i++, x+=in_steps) {
            vertex(x, y, matrix[i][j]);
            vertex(x, y + in_steps, matrix[i][j+1]);
        }
        endShape();
    }
}

void mousePressed()
{
    lastX = mouseX;
    lastY = mouseY;
}

void mouseDragged()
{ 
    distX = radians(mouseX - lastX);
    distY = radians(lastY - mouseY);
}

void mouseReleased()
{
    rotX += distY;
    rotY += distX;
    distX = distY = 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`lights()`](https://processing.org/reference/lights_.html) are already proper set in your code.

Use [`noStroke()`](https://processing.org/reference/noStroke_.html) to get rid of the lines. `noStroke` disables drawing outlines.

The color of the filled areas can be set by passing RGB (red, green and blue) values to [`fill()`](https://processing.org/reference/fill_.html).
The values are integral values in the range[0, 255]. The RGB vlaue for red is (255, 0, 0) and the RGB value for yellow is (255, 255, 0).

A gradient color form red to yellow can be achieved by

```java
fill(255, z*255, 0);
```

where z is in [0.0, 1.0]. If `z = 0.0` the result is red (255, 0, 0) and if `z = 1.0` the result is yellow (255, 255, 0). All values for z in between 0.0 and 1.0 result in a linear interpolation between read and yellow.

e.g.

```java
for (j = 0, y = 0.0; j < steps; j++, y+=in_steps) {
    beginShape(QUAD_STRIP);

    noStroke(); // no lines

    for (i = 0, x = 0.0; i <= steps; i++, x+=in_steps) {

        fill(255, matrix[i][j] * 255, 0); // interpolate between red and yellow
        vertex(x, y, matrix[i][j]);

        fill(255, matrix[i][j+1] * 255, 0); // interpolate between red and yellow
        vertex(x, y + in_steps, matrix[i][j+1]);
    }
    endShape();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it a lot, I was struggling with this.